# Is it the answer or the question that makes a question duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Meaning, even if both questions have the same answer, but the 2 questions are not similar, (For example, each question describe a different part of the story) Should they be considered duplicates?

I always assumed it's the question, but does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Do you mean specifically with ID questions?

Comment: That's what I'm more interested at, but I asked the question in general. I thought there will be a clear cut answer to apply to all questions.

Comment: I always had this question.

Answer (score 7):

I would only recommend closing two questions as duplicates based on an answer in the case of ID questions where **both questions have accepted answers**.

**In general**, it is incorrect to dupe close based on the answer. Just because two questions have the same answer does not mean that they are the same question.

> What is the answer of 3 * 8?
>   What is the answer of 4 * 6?

These are **not** duplicate questions, despite the fact that the answer in both cases is "24".

From a tangentially related [Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258325/284336):

> There's only one problem with your feature request: **answers don't make questions duplicates**. Questions are duplicates only when the questions themselves are duplicates. In other words, you can't close a question as a duplicate of another question just because "you can find your answer over here."

Comment: That's what I always assumed "..not duplicate & answers don't make questions duplicates" for all questions,(ID s included), I'm asking now because I realized otherwise.

Comment: I think your two math problems _are_ duplicate questions, and the answer isn't "24", but "here's how basic multiplication of single digit numbers works" — or "here's how to use a calculator". That way, there can be one great answer (or several, but collected) that really solves the problem, rather than having 100 different questions with varying degrees of answer.

Comment: @mattdm I picked an extremely oversimplified example on purpose. We aren't a math site, anyway, so it's not even a question that would be asked here. It's for illustration.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but it's often conceptually the same.

Comment: @mattdm Unless you have a more specific example, I don't really follow. SE **in general** does not close as dupes based on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the Answer is the same (especially and primarily with ID questions) then it's the **Answer that makes it a Duplicate**.

Linking the Questions as Duplicates means that they all become signposts to the correct answer.

The [**Vantage Point**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72006/action-movie-which-shows-the-story-of-a-terrorist-attack-on-the-us-president-fro) questions are a good example here. All of them are asking about the same movie from, heh, different perspectives and/or plot points.

Nevertheless, the answer is the same in each instance..thus "Duplicate".

Comment: Thanks, and lol at "different perspectives".

Comment: I'd say this is **only** in relation to ID... if then. In general, we do not dupe closed based on answers.

Answer (score -6):

The normal SE policy is that duplicates are only for questions. You can have the same answer on multiple questions in a technical sense with the questions being completely unrelated.

But since M&TV is not a technical sight, the mods have come up with their own scheme. **Which makes no sense**. Basing duplicates on answers leads to the second question, asked in a significantly different way, being closed. Then eventually deleted. Both closed and deleted question status means it does not get indexed by SE search or Google, which means searches for those terms do not come up with a result, which leads to people asking for the same movie, again in different ways. So basing duplicates on answers mean more duplicates will occur.

Also, you cannot close a question as a dupe of a question without an accepted answer in the first place.

Comment: This is just wrong. Questions that have non-negative scores and are closed as duplicates **do not** get deleted. The existence of three duped *Point Break* ID questions clearly shows that this is wrong. If the question is good quality, it should be upvoted and if it's low-quality and gets downvoted, there's no reason to keep it around any more than any other closed, downvoted question.

Comment: It's also incorrect that it's not indexed: *In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.* https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled